# How to only add a number to a vector if it doesn't already exist in it?

Tags: java, vector

This is for a simple exercise with vectors (I know, outdated). I need to make a code that only adds an inputed number to the vector if it doesn't exist already. If it does exist, I need to ask the user to try again until it's a valid number. My code looks like this:

```
public void readVector(int[] vector) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Input a number for position " + i + ": ");
        vector[i] = s.nextInt();
        for (int j = 0; j < vector.length; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                if (vector[i] == vector[j]) {
                    System.out.print("Value already exists in vector. Input a valid number: ");
                    vector[i] = s.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works to some extent. If I repeat a number it will ask to try again until the number is valid, however, if I were to input, say, 1 to vector[0], then 2 to vector[1] and then try 1 again (which already exists) it will work and not ask for a new number, because of something in the if validation I just can't work out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why this condition `if (i != j)`?

Comment: Because if i = 0 and j = 0 comparing a number to itself (vector[0] to vector[0]) wouldn't make sense, I guess.

Comment: Regarding your first sentence… You may be conflating arrays and the [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Vector.html) class. The `Vector` class is old, and has been supplanted by `ArrayList` for many years. Arrays are still very much in vogue, for use in cases where a [Java Collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) class is overkill.

Comment: @BasilBourque I think with vectors he just refers to the mathematical way to name arrays.

Comment: I think it's time to learn how to debug, it will be a useful skill in the future, trust me :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void readVector(int[] vector) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Input a number for position " + i + ": ");
        int input = s.nextInt();
        while(vectorContainsInput(vector, input)) {
            System.out.print("Value already exists in vector. Input a valid number: ");
            input = s.nextInt();
        }
        vector[i] = input;
    }
}

public boolean vectorContainsInput(int [] vector, int input) {
    return Arrays.stream(vector).anyMatch(value -> value == input);
}
```